# How can I convert MYSQL tables to a PHP install script in PHPMyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there any way to convert *all* tables to a PHP install script? Now I create tables directly using phpmyadmin and have to program a PHP script to install those exact tables. I assume this can be automated?

'show create table' only exports a single table. I am using phpmyadmin 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From phpMyAdmin, you can export only the structure of a database rather easily.

From the database view (not a specific table), click the Export tab along the top of the screen. Then select "Custom" as the Export Method and about halfway down look for the heading "Format-specific options". At the bottom of that section are a series of radio buttons where you can select structure, data, or structure and data. Sounds like you wish only to have structure. This will allow you to generate an SQL file that will recreate the table structure.

[image]

Once you've got the SQL file, it's rather simple to execute those statements to MySQL (you could copy and paste directly in to query you're executing, you could source the entire file in to MySQL via PHP, or a couple of other means), but it sounds like you've already got a method for that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just export the create table scripts and let it run in the install php script.